# how to foreach enum from except first item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is enum

```
public enum SportTypeEnum
{
    [EnumDescription("not defined")]
    Null = 0,

    [EnumDescription("football")]
    FootBall = 100,

    [EnumDescription("volyball")]
    VollyBall = 110,

    [EnumDescription("basketball")]
    BasketBall = 120,

    [EnumDescription("Swimming")]
    wrestling = 140,
}
```

I can loop through all element like below

```
var sportTypeValueList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SportTypeEnum));
@foreach (SportTypeEnum sportTypeEnum in sportTypeValueList)
{                   
    <option value="@(sportTypeEnum.ToString())" @(dataUi != null && dataUi.SportType == sportTypeEnum ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>
        @EnumUtilities.GetEnumDescription(sportTypeEnum)
    </option>
}
```

but how can loop through item except first item?
thanks

Comment: `sportTypeValueList.Where(v => v != 0)`?

Comment: `sportTypeValueList.Skip(1)`

Comment: @maccettura [`GetValues()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) is documented to return the values in order of their absolute values, so yes this is guaranteed to work because `0` will ALWAYS be returned as the first element. `The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude).`

Comment: @MatthewWatson My mid morning brain apparently skipped right past the sentence.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not just make the property nullable and omit the first option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use an if statement to exclude the `None` option rather than excluding the "first" option:

```
var sportTypeValueList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SportTypeEnum));
@foreach(SportTypeEnum sportTypeEnum in sportTypeValueList)
{
    @if(sportTypeEnum != SportTypeEnum.Null)
    {
        <option value = "@(sportTypeEnum.ToString())" @(dataUi != null && dataUi.SportType == sportTypeEnum ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") >
           @EnumUtilities.GetEnumDescription(sportTypeEnum)
        </option >
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my thought also - it makes it much more obvious to future maintainers why you're skipping it

Comment: Yes. It also doesn't matter whether the Null option is actually defined as the "first" (default) option.